# Using on demand resources, is it possible to download list of files if they are unknown at buildtime?

Tags: ios, host, on-demand-resources

I want to get list of files by network at runtime. I am planning to host a lot of files (spritekit atlas) on my server. I want users to be able to download this files into the app. Since I don’t know at the moment how many files I am going to have, can I still use ODR and let users download newly added files without having to compile a new build of the app.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain what you have tried so far and what your specific question is. You may find this handy: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could create a manifest / payload JSON file on your server which the app downloads first, then reads through to find all the files it needs to download. You can then also periodically check for a revised manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is to use Apple's ODR with Xcode, I am fairly certain you need to bundle those resources with the application and then tag them as ODR. At runtime, the application will download those files as necessary.

As far as I am aware, there is no other means by which you can modify the available ODR except by releasing a new version with the updated assets included in the bundle and tagged as downloadable. Apple is generally not a fan of resources being modified in an application after their approval process is complete so I would be surprised if you could upload whatever you like after the fact without modifying the bundle and resubmitting.